# I need to be able to overlay pictures and panels (a math equation)

Tags: java, swing

I am using this class to make an image have different states. At first, the image is dark grey (so you can't see it). I want the image to be clickable and once clicked a math equation will appear. Once the equation is answered the full image will appear. Also, I have another class that splits an image into separate pieces. So basically all of those separate pieces inherit this method. So it's a picture that has been divided into separate images (let's say 4 images, so that means 4 math problems). How would I go about doing this. I've tried multiple methods (that I haven't included in this because it looked like a rats nest), but haven't been able to get it work. I've tried implementing `mouseListener` and `OverlayLayout`, but haven't gotten it to work.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * Makes the image have different states
 */
public class GPanel extends JPanel {
    private Image img;
    private boolean answered;
    private boolean working;
    private int w;
    private int h;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public GPanel(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
        w = img.getWidth(this);
        h = img.getHeight(this);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
        answered = false;
        working = false;
    }

    public void setAnswered() {
        answered = true;
    }

    public boolean getAnswered() {
        return answered;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if (!answered) {
            if (working){
                System.out.println("Run third");
                g2.setColor(Color.lightGray);
                g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
                g2.setPaint(Color.yellow);
                g2.setFont(new Font("Sans-serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
                g2.drawString("Testing, one, two, three.", w/3, h/2);
                ((JFrame)SwingUtilities.getRoot(this)).setTitle("Testing, one, two, three.");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Run first");
                g2.setColor(Color.darkGray);
                g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
            }
            working = !working;  // toggles on and off
        } else {
            System.out.println("Run second");
            g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
            ((JFrame)SwingUtilities.getRoot(this)).setTitle("Testing GPanel");
        }
        answered = !answered; // toggles on and off 
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got code within your paintComponent method that changes the state of the object, something that you want to avoid, since you never have full control over when or even if this method is called. Instead, change the logic elsewhere in response to whatever events you need to listen to, call repaint, and then use paintComponent only to display the visual results of these state changes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels
Are you referring to where it says "toggles on and off?" My logic was to make methods that will return working and answered to true and false. Therefore deleting the current `answered = !answered; // toggles on and off` and `working = !working;  // toggles on and off` but I just don't know how to get the mouseListener to work. And also don't know where to add my math equation panel in this `GPanel` class.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is to swap images, then the easiest way to do that is to display the images as ImageIcons within a JLabel. To swap the JLabel's icon, all one has to do is simply call `setIcon(newIcon)` on the JLabel. So for instance, say we had four images within an ArrayList of Icons (`ArrayList<Icon>`) and that this ArrayList variable was called icons, and say your program had an int variable called iconIndex that holds the index number of the current image being displayed, then it's simple to swap images by incrementing the index variable, and using it to get the next icon in the list. Something like:

```
iconIndex++;   // increment the index variable
iconIndex %= icons.size();  // if larger than size of list, set to 0
Icon icon = icons.get(iconIndex); // get icon from list
imageLabel.setIcon(icon); // set the JLabel's icon with it
```

This code could be within a MouseListener, one added to the JLabel, and then you're done. Note that the logic code is in the MouseListener. So if the user has to do anything else before an image is switched, it is checked within the same MouseListener

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DifferentImages extends JPanel {
    private static final int IMG_W = 400;
    private static final int IMG_H = IMG_W;
    private static final Font TEXT_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 40);
    private JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
    private List<Icon> icons = new ArrayList<>();
    private int iconIndex = 0;

    public DifferentImages() {
        // create images and icons
        Icon icon = getIcon(Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.LIGHT_GRAY, "First Image");        
        icons.add(icon);
        icon = getIcon(Color.BLUE, new Color(137, 207, 240), "Second Image");
        icons.add(icon);
        icon = getIcon(Color.RED, Color.PINK, "Third Image");
        icons.add(icon);
        icon = getIcon(Color.YELLOW, Color.ORANGE, "Fourth Image");
        icons.add(icon);        

        imageLabel.setIcon(icons.get(iconIndex));        
        add(imageLabel);

        imageLabel.addMouseListener(new MyMouse());
    }

    // MouseListener that is added to JLabel
    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // code here to check if it is OK to swap images
            // and if so, then swap them:
            iconIndex++;   // increment the index variable
            iconIndex %= icons.size();  // if larger than size of list, set to 0
            Icon icon = icons.get(iconIndex); // get icon from list
            imageLabel.setIcon(icon); // set the JLabel's icon with it
        }
    }

    // just creates an image icon for demo purposes, one with color and text
    private Icon getIcon(Color bg, Color fb, String text) {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(IMG_W, IMG_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(bg); // first a dark image
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, IMG_W, IMG_H);
        g2.setColor(fb);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setFont(TEXT_FONT);
        FontMetrics fontMetrics = g2.getFontMetrics(TEXT_FONT);
        int textWidth = fontMetrics.stringWidth(text);
        int x = (IMG_W - textWidth) / 2;
        int y = (IMG_H) / 2;
        g2.drawString(text, x, y);
        g2.dispose();
        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
        return icon;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DifferentImages");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new DifferentImages());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: No it's not that I need to swap images. Basically, a user chooses an image and once chosen that image is split up into separate pieces. Under each separate piece is a math equation that the user has to answer. At first, the images are grey, then when you click on them the math problem appears. Once you answer the problem correctly, the image is shown. This goes on until all questions are answered and then the split up image is shown whole again. 

I'm really sorry for the confusion. Because I know you took the time to write code. I appreciate it.

Comment: `   addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
              if (img.getSource() == e.getSource()){
               answered = true;
               working = true;
               repaint();
              }
    }
   });` Is what I thought might work, but it doesn't.

Comment: In your other code you're adding a MouseListener to a JLabel, lb, that's never added to the GUI, that's not visible, so it can't work. A MouseListener only works on displayed components.

Comment: @Trey: And your requirements in the comment above could still work in something along the lines of the code above. In the mouseListener commented lines, you have code to see if this is the first click or not. If first, show the math equation. If 2nd, check to see if answered correctly, and if so, swap images. The way to solve this is to use the ideas presented above, but not the exact code.